# Selenium screenshot of multiple elements

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

Im using Python Selenium to scrape a website. At some point during the scrape i want to take a screenshot. I only 'roughly' want to take a screenshot covering specific WebElements. How do I take a screenshot of section containing multiple WebElements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To avoid an eventual [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info/), here is how you can screenshot any particular element you want, with Selenium (Python) - that element can be a div encompassing other elements:

```
[...]
url = 'https://www.startech.com.bd/benq-gw2480-fhd-monitor'
browser.get(url) 
browser.execute_script('window.scrollBy(0, 100);')
elem = WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//section[@id='specification']")))
elem.screenshot('fullspec.png')

print('screenshotted specs')
```

Se Selenium documentation [here](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/).